# Insecure world writable dir

Tags: mac-osx, ruby

I can't figure out how to fix this, apparently ruby doesn't like anything in my home directory.

```
/Users/Connor/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/Connor/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin in PATH, mode 040766
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chmod -R o-w ~/.rvm

Comment: Translated for folks that don't do octal: remove the world-write bit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is just a warning, and Ruby should still run even with this Warning message.

It appears that /Users/Connor/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin has permissions 766, which probably looks like this:

drwxrw-rw-  2 connor  yourgroup  68 Apr 13 14:03 bin

This is not secure, because it means anyone with access to your system could install files under /Users/Connor/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin, and you might execute those unknown files by accident.

Run this command from the commandline:

```
chmod go-rw /Users/Connor/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin
```

This will disallow anyone but you from writing to and reading from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your umask settings are likely improperly set, enabling files to be created with less than secure settings.

The other solutions posted were about fixing the permissions issue, but not fixing the umask issue that is likely a part of it.